# Can't find Windows DDK documentation

Tags: windows, documentation

I am looking for Windows DDK documentation, but I can't find it anywhere - not even in MSDN.

For example, I can't find the documentation of KeGetActiveProcessors function, for getting ammount of active processors.

Comment: Are you looking for [`KeQueryActiveProcessorCount` and `KeQueryActiveProcessors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551830(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @JosefZ Yea, among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am looking for Windows DDK documentation

The DDK is now known as the WDK. See below for download instructions.

> Previously, the WDK was known as Windows Driver Development Kit (DDK) and supported Windows Driver Model (WDM) development. It got its current name when Microsoft released Windows Vista and added the following tools to the kit:
>
> - Windows Driver Foundation (WDF)
> - Installable File System Kit (IFS Kit)
> - Driver Test Manager (DTM)

Source [Windows Driver Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Kit)

The WDK documentation can be downloaded from [Microsoft's github account](https://github.com/Microsoft/windows-driver-docs):

> **Windows Driver Documentation**
>
> Welcome to the Windows driver docs repository, housing the source for
>   the official Windows Driver Kit documentation available on MSDN.
>   Contributing
>
> We actively merge contributions into this repository via pull request
>   into the staging branch (for the public repo) or the master branch
>   (for the private repo).
>
> For more information on contributing, read our contributions guide.
>   Microsoft Code of Conduct
>
> This project has adopted the Microsoft Open Source Code of Conduct.
>   For more information see the Code of Conduct FAQ or contact
>   opencode@microsoft.com with any additional questions or comments.

Source [Windows Driver Documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/windows-driver-docs/blob/staging/README.md)

---

#### Windows Driver Kit (WDK)

> Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 10 is integrated with Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2015 and Debugging Tools for Windows. This integrated environment
>   gives you the tools you need to develop, build, package, deploy, test,
>   and debug drivers. You can run many basic certification tests in the
>   integrated environment. The Windows Driver Kit (WDK) includes
>   templates for several technologies and driver models, including
>   Windows Driver Frameworks (WDF), Universal Serial Bus (USB), print,
>   networking, and file system filters.
>
> **How to get WDK 10**
>
> Install [Visual Studio 2015 with the SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=733614), and then install [WDK
>   10](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=733614).
>
> [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) is included in WDK 10, so you don't
>   need to download it separately.

Source [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

#### I'm looking for `KeQueryActiveProcessorCount` and `KeQueryActiveProcessors`

You can find these online in the MSDN documentation (Core Kernel Library Support Routines).

- [KeQueryActiveProcessorCount routine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552985(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [KeQueryActiveProcessors routine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553001(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find what I asked for.. And I believe I have well searched. For example, where is the documentation of KeQueryActiveProcessorCount in this github repo?

Comment: What you are looking for is online. Answer updated.